# How to recover randomly generated private key from a Program that implements Diffie Hellman Exchange

Tags: ida, disassembly, encryption

This program implements Diffie Hellman key Exchange, a pair of random private keys are generated every time the program runs. How should I go about finding the random number generation subroutine using a disassembler like IDA?

Warning: The program is flagged as malware by Windows Defender.
hxxps://drive.google.com/open?id=1uErzKPIV-HyOBunn0ecF6pehXJ_mDdGR

Comment: It's a PyInstaller generated executable. IDA is not quite the right tool here. To answer the question the RNG is `randint(2, 198)`. You can find it after you've extracted the pyc's from the exe.

Comment: I extracted pyc files from the exe file, but I am unable to decompile DH file, decompiler says magic number mismatch.  How did you decompile DH file?

Comment: You need to add a 16 byte signature for Python 3.7 at the beginning of the pyc. Without that the decompiler won't recognize it as a pyc file.